# mysql trigger executes php file before data is commited

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a trigger in MySQL that executes a PHP file when a row is inserted, this is the trigger :

```
AFTER INSERT ON \glpi_tickets \
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN\``

BEGIN

DECLARE result INT;

SET result = (select sys_exec('C:/xampp/php/php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/lar/query.php'));

END
```

In that PHP file, I query the last ID using this query :

`SELECT MAX(\id\) FROM glpi_tickets;`

But I get the ID before the one just inserted even tho the trigger is after insert on, it's like I query then the row is added like I'm using before insert on or the the php file executes before the row is commited either, so to make the php file executes after the row is commited or is there a way to get the row just inserted guys?

I really need this appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no support for a trigger that runs after a transaction is committed. You should do that in your application code.

If you run an external PHP script from a trigger, that PHP script must create its own connection to the database, and therefore its own transaction. It has no visibility to the uncommitted transaction that spawned your trigger, or the changes created in that uncommitted transaction. This is by design, it is the nature of an ACID database.

It seems like you want to get the id of the row you just inserted. In that case, you don't need any of the stuff you've been doing. You just use:

```
OR EACH ROW BEGIN

BEGIN

DECLARE result INT;

SET result = NEW.id;

END
```

Although I don't know what is the purpose of saving that in a local variable in the trigger. Unless you have additional code in the trigger that you're not showing.